# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family

Tags: java, web-services, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Javax Client gives below error , While using

```
Builder request = webTarget.request();
return request.get();
```

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:263)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:668)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)    at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228) Caused
>   by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.(Statuses.java:63)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses$StatusImpl.(Statuses.java:54)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.Statuses.from(Statuses.java:143)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:338)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:242)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:254)

This could be because of Javax client version , There is not compilation error only during execution i'm seeing above exception

POM :

```
<dependency>
                <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
                <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
                <version>6.9.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
                <dependency>
                <groupId>org.fluttercode.datafactory</groupId>
                <artifactId>datafactory</artifactId>
                <version>0.8</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>

            <!-- ObjectMapper dependencies start .. -->

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.4</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
                <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- ObjectMapper dependencies End.. -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>2.19</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>


         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <exclusions>
               <!--  Causes java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response$Status$Family.familyOf(I)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family; -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I think it is happening because `jsr311-api.jar`is present in your class path. Looking at your pom.xml, you have already excluded it in one of the artifacts where this dependency is present. Still, can you check your classpath for any `jsr311-api.jar` dependency?

Comment: I checked in Maven repo , jsr311-api.jar is not present .

Comment: @Jagadeesh Did you ever figure out what was wrong here and what the fix was?